# Why can't I apply the method for proving that finite integral domain is field to proving that infite one is field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In abstract algebra, it proves that finite integral domain is a field as like this:

Let 0,1,a1,a2,•••,an be all elements of a finite domain D. We need to show that for a in D, there exists b in D such that ab is in D. All a1,aa1,aa2,•••,aan are in D and are distinct by cancellation laws. And since there is no divisors of 0, none of them are 0. So that either a1=1, or aai=1 for some i.

How about using this method for proving that infinte integral domain is a field? Let D-{0} as subset D1and aD1 is in D and all element in D1 is distinct. And none of them are 0. So D1 is mapped onto D1 by one to one function f:c->ac. So that a in D1 has multiplicative inverse in D1.

But contradiction example is Z. What is wrong with above proof?

Comment: Click on edit/improve in the other discussion to see how we type in mathjax. Sure this is the natural method to show a finite integral domain is a field : $a^j= a^i \implies a a^{j-i-1} = 1$. Obviously we need the finite assumption to find such $j> i$.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that an injection $X\to X$ must be a bijection (and hence onto) when $X$ is finite, but not when $X$ is infinite.

In the finite domain case, the list $aa_1,aa_2,\ldots,aa_n$ gives you an embedding/injection $D\to D$, mapping $a_i$ to $aa_i$; since $D$ is finite, it must be onto, so one of those elements must be $1$, etc.

In the infinite case, you know $aa_1,aa_2,\ldots$ are all distinct, so you get an embedding $D\to D$; but now that it is infinite, you **cannot** conclude that one of the elements in that list must be equal to $1$.

In fact, that is what happens. Take $\mathbb{Z}$, which you know to be a domain but not a field. The map $z\longmapsto 2z$ is an embedding from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself, but no elements of the image is equal to $1$ (you cannot conclude one of them must be because all you know is that the function is one-to-one, not that it is onto). Hence, you cannot conclude that $2z=1$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Remark:** Here is a good exercise: you *know* the proof must be wrong, because you have a counterexample, namely $\mathbb{Z}$. *Apply the argument to the counterexample!* That will let you spot *exactly* where the argument isn’t working, since you can see it not working *explicitly*. Here, you will see the error is in the assertion that $1$ must equal some $aa_n$. So that allows you isolate exactly what step is going wrong, and you can think through why it works in the finite case but not in the infinite case.

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is infinite, a one-to-one function from $D$ to $D$ need not be surjective.

Hence for nonzero $a\in D$, the map from $D$ to $D$ given by $x\mapsto ax$, though injective, may not have $1$ in its range.